# No request mapping for url

Tags: spring-mvc

In my spring mvc project the login page is served as a direct url host/context/login.jsp.

My web.xml states dispatcher-servlet url pattern as:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern> / </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml is below:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company" />

<mvc:resources location="/, /assets/"
mapping="/assets/**" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:METAINF/spring/application.properties" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=iup"/>
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:logout />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/WEB-INF/jsp/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
</security:http>
```

Also I have a jsp file login.jsp just above the WEB-INF folder for direct access.

On my local machine when I do localhost:8080/context/login.jsp everyting runs fine and login.jsp is rendered but on server machine the call is intercepted by DispatcherServlet and it tries to find a corresponding url mapping(which is not present). What could possibly be making it happen. The logs for catalina.out at server machine are as:

```
-DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing GET request for [/context/login.jsp]
-command not found
-Looking up handler method for path /login.jsp
-command not found
-Did not find handler method for [/login.jsp]
-command not found
-No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/context/login.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

Comment: You didn't map the URL to a handler. You'll need to create a controller and the appropriate @RequestMapping.

Comment: Could we please see your MVC controller that send the user to the view.

Comment: *Possible typo:* Should `classpath*:METAINF` not be `classpath*:META-INF`?

Comment: add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to your configuration.

Comment: @Bart: that is actually META-INF. It was mistakenly typed here

Comment: @bart : I tried putting login.jsp behind a controoller with mapping /auth/login but after Dispatcher servlet resolves the view to login .jsp and forwards to it the forwarded call is again intercepted by dispatcher servlet and again the same error is displayed for the view.

Comment: Why are you mapping to */auth/login* when you specify */login.jsp* as your login page?